# regular expression for match 1 alphabet, 1 digit and allow all special characters

Tags: regex, passwords

In my website(PHP, Mysql), I am using the below regular expression for validate password

```
^(?=.*[0-9]+.*)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]+.*)[0-9a-zA-Z]{6,}$
```

I got this from http://regexlib.com/. This validate minimum 6 characters which should have atleast one alphabet and one numeric character. It will not allow any special characters

**I need to allow all the special characters also.**

How could I modify this? I am not familiar with regular expressions. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add the special characters you want to allow in the character class:

```
^(?=.*[0-9]+.*)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]+.*)[0-9a-zA-Z.!&/()=?+*~#'_:.,;-]{6,}$
```

Answer (score 1):

```
^(?=.*[0-9]+.*)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]+.*)[0-9a-zA-Z-!$%^&*()_+|~=`{}\[\]:";'<>?,.\/]{6,}$
```

You just have to add special characters to your existing character class.

Answer (score 1):

Why use lookahead ?

```
\A[0-9a-zA-Z.!&/()=?+*~#'_:.,;-]{6,}\z
```

Comment: This would accept `.......` as a valid password. The OP probably wants to ensure that the password contains at least one digit, and one alphabet.